# Introductory reading on classifiers that are not "yes/no" naive Bayes

Tags: statistics

I want to manually implement a classifier for certain short strings of words, getting a "goodness" rank for each of them.  I have made a naive Bayesian classifier which is basically spam-filter-like and scores strings based on previous "good"/"bad" ratings. So far so good.
Now, there are two problems that I want to solve (by properly understanding things)...

**The question is** - what would be good introductory material for below, not of "cookbook" variety but more systematic, and yet ideally shorter than a university statistics course :)  Set of articles that is shorter than the book, or a good book. Aimed at programmers ideally.

The problems are:
first, in my system there are actually 3 types of user feedback - "good", "bad", and "neutral". Most items are neutral, and right now I simply don't include them in the ranking. I am wondering how these things are properly handled (I still need to obtain a single "goodness probability" per item, so if I calculate probability of good and bad separately, are there any pitfalls/proper methods to combining those).
Then, I want to remove the naive part from my classifier (i.e. take relations between words into account), so some different classifier may be in order. Or, I could add all pairs-triples-etc. of words as features, since the strings are short - this feels like a hack, but then again my CS/maths background is rusty enough and/or insufficient to say whether this is a valid technique.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this question gets closed. If that happens, it might be worth trying http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look at basic elements of the subject of "Probabilistic Graphical Models" for introducing relationships between variables. There was a coursera course on this stuff, by Daphne Koller.